# How can jersey check what was the requested data format?

Tags: java, web-services, api, rest, jersey

I wonder how to check what data client request from rest API

for example I have api like:

```
@POST
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML  })
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML }){
    ...some logic;
    }
```

if client has header:

```
Accept: application/xml
```

than I want him to get different response than if he had application/json in header. So can I make somethink like

```
  @POST
        @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML  })
        @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML}){ 
    if ( mediaType.equals("APPLICATION_JSON"){   (its pseudo code)
    blah blah blah}; 
        }}
```

???

Comment: That's not very RESTful. XML or JSON should be just representations of the same resource. What kind of difference would you like to make based on the `Accept` header that is not jus a different in the format of the response?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`HeaderParam` annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/HeaderParam.html) to access the value of the `Accept` header.

```
@POST
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML  })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public Response myPostService(@HeaderParam("Accept") String accepted, 
                              MyObject inTheRequestBody) {
   MediaType mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON; // the default
   if(accepted != null) {
       mediaType = MediaType.valueOf(accepted);
   }
   // service logic
   return Response.ok().entity(/*the object you want to return*/).type(mediaType).build();
}
```

Jersey will just take care of the serialization for you, provided that it has the corresponding 
[`MessageBodyReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html) (for the request body) and 
[`MessageBodyWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html). If it doesn't, you can always register your own and Jersey will invoke it.

Comment: That's a good answer. Using backticks for markup of code/class names/header names makes it more readable. And if you can link to JavaDoc, it will become even more useful

Comment: @LutzHorn 
Thanx, it works, how can I added second parameter to method which will be used in function  as json (body from request)?

Comment: I edited the post to include the request body in the method signature.